# What can I use to simulate light reflection that can also give me the irradiance value on a specific surface?

Tags: optics, simulation

i am looking for software that can simulate things like mirrors and how light reflects from them (this exists) but I also want the program to give me the irradiance or any relevant photo metric value on a specific surface. For example I might put a mirror and an opaque surface, when I simulate it I want it to give me how much light is actually hitting the surface, for example an irradiance value (watt/m2).

Comment: Perhaps Ansys Speos? I haven't used that tool myself so I'm not sure.